# Pythonic way to strip all 0's from the front of a string

Tags: python

I have a string that will later be converted with `int()`. It is three digits, anywhere from 0 to 3 of them might be 0's. How would I strip the 0s from the left side of the string?

Now I'm using `string.lstrip('0')` but that strips all the 0s and makes the string empty, causing an error.

Comment: I like the question "what is the pythonic way to strip 0s from the front of the string" but your saying that later it will be converted with `int()` seems to be a total red herring.  Does it have anything at all to do with the question?  Because `int` isn't going to care about the leading zeros.

Comment: @RayToal: He means that he wants to strip leading zeros *and* the result must be a valid input for `int(s)`. The latter of course is automatic, as long as you do the first step correctly.

Comment: if your concern is really just about the number beeing read as octal (like in your comments to ignacio's answer): `int` does not do that in python. `int('010')` would be `10`, `int('010', 0)` whould be `8`. If you want to be specific about it, just use `int('010', 10)`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
s = str(int(s))
```

Another alternative is:

```
s = s.lstrip('0') or '0'
```

Answer (score 5):

You want `str.lstrip()` for that. But maybe you should just pass the radix to `int()`.

Comment: That only strips one 0. I need to do this because Python interprets it as an Octal string.

Comment: @Cheezey: no, it strips multiple 0s.

Comment: Oh, it worked, but there was a different problem. Posting it in the main question now.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I think passing the radix is unnecessary.  The octal problem comes in when parsing literals in source, not when int('0123') does its work, no?

Comment: @DSM `int('0123')` is 123 but `int('0123',8)` is 83.

Comment: @RayToal: er, yes.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding -- I thought he was stripping zeroes unnecessarily to try to *avoid* a string being parsed as octal when it wasn't intended as such.  Are you suggesting that instead his string *is* in base 8?  If so, why would he need to strip it in the first place?

Comment: @DSM: His question is how to strip the leading zeros on a string like "012" -> "12" and "000" -> "0". It's a fairly normal and straight-forward question, don't you agree? Nothing to do with octal.

Comment: @DSM good question, I have no idea.  I've asked the OP in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

what about `string[:-1].lstrip('0')`? :D