# Number to string conversion with f-string without leading or trailing zeros?

Tags: python, string, format, f-string

> **Update:** as up to now (2019-09), masking leading or trailing zeros in decimal numbers formatted to string seems to be unsupported in
>   Python. You will need to use a workaround to get something like '.01'
>   from the number 0.0101 (assuming 3 decimal places desired).
>
> I would even argue that it's a good thing **not** to support such a format
>   since
>
> - I'd consider '0.01' be better in terms of readability than '.01'
> - '0.010' carries information (3 digits of precision...) that is lost in '0.01'
>
> If desired anyway, one could use one of the suggestions below. Thank you all for contributing.

**Q:** I'm looking for a way to output floating point numbers as strings, formatted **without leading/trailing zeros**. Is there a way to do this with `'{ }'.format()` or f-string? I searched the internet but didn't find anything. Did I just miss it or is it not possible (Python 3.7)?
What I have in mind is basically

```py
some_number = 0.3140
string = f'{some_number:x}' # giving '.314'
```

that gives the output `string '.314'.`. So is there an `x` that does this?

Of course one could work-around with `lstrip` / `rstrip` as described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142347/how-to-remove-leading-and-trailing-zeros-in-a-string-python) or [similar here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860048/pythonic-way-to-strip-all-0s-from-the-front-of-a-string):

```py
In [93]: str(0.3140).lstrip('0').rstrip('0')
Out[93]: '.314'
```

but it would be more convenient to use *only* an f-string. Since I can use that for other formatting options, optionally calling `strip` demands additional lines of code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to strip all 0's from the front of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860048/pythonic-way-to-strip-all-0s-from-the-front-of-a-string)

Comment: @gpk, I am NOT looking for a `strip` method. I made an edit to clarify.

Comment: oh, alright @MrFuppes, maybe this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303797/print-floating-point-values-without-leading-zero

Comment: @gpk27, thanks, but I looked into the answers that were given in the [Q&A you suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303797/print-floating-point-values-without-leading-zero). Seems to be another hack; defining new classes it not what I have in mind.

Comment: I don't know if this fits your requirement, but you can combine f-strings with the `strip()` methods by using `string = f'{(str(some_number).lstrip("0").rstrip("0"))}' `.

Comment: @JackFleeting: thanks for the comment, I also was thinking about something like that. Basically I think now after some additional research that Python number-to-string format options do not support masking of leading/trailing zeros (I think it is a good thing not to support this btw.). One *must* use the `strip` work-around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a helper function that I came up with since the `strip` workaround can't be avoided:

```py
def dec2string_stripped(num, dec_places=3, strip='right'):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    num : float or list of float
        scalar or list of decimal numbers.
    dec_places : int, optional
        number of decimal places to return. defaults to 3.
    strip : string, optional
        what to strip. 'right' (default), 'left' or 'both'.

    Returns
    -------
    list of string.
        numbers formatted as strings according to specification (see kwargs).
    """
    if not isinstance(num, list): # might be scalar or numpy array
        try:
            num = list(num)
        except TypeError: # input was scalar
            num = [num]

    if not isinstance(dec_places, int) or int(dec_places) < 1:
        raise ValueError(f"kwarg dec_places must be integer > 1 (got {dec_places})")

    if strip == 'right':
        return [f"{n:.{str(dec_places)}f}".rstrip('0') for n in num]
    if strip == 'left':
        return [f"{n:.{str(dec_places)}f}".lstrip('0') for n in num]
    if strip == 'both':
        return [f"{n:.{str(dec_places)}f}".strip('0') for n in num]
    raise ValueError(f"kwarg 'strip' must be 'right', 'left' or 'both' (got '{strip}')")
```

Answer (score 1):

just to mention it here... if you use `numpy` there's also the function [`np.format_float_positional()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_positional.html) that gives you full control of how to display numbers as strings and trim trailing zeros...

from the doc of `np.format_float_positional`:

> Format a floating-point scalar as a decimal string in positional notation.
>
> Provides control over rounding, trimming and padding. Uses and assumes IEEE >unbiased rounding. Uses the "Dragon4" algorithm.

getting rid of the leading zero is then just a simple check whether we're dealing with a number that starts with 0 or not

```py
import numpy as np
def format_float(x, trim_leading=True, **kwargs):
    s = np.format_float_positional(x, **kwargs)
    if trim_leading is True and int(x) == 0 and len(s) > 1:
        s = s.replace("0.", ".")
    return s
```

```py
format_float(0.0234001232, trim_leading=True, precision=4)
>>> '.0234'
format_float(0.0234001232, trim_leading=False, precision=4)
>>> '0.0234'
format_float(0.0234001232, precision=8)
>>> '0.02340012'
format_float(12.000558, precision=2, trim="-", fractional=False)
>>> '12'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to just strip 0 from floating numbers you could use this "hack"

```
"." + str(0.314).split("0.")[-1]
```

this is in no way an elegant solution, but it will get the job done

also if you want to use .format as well you don't need another line, you could just

```
"." +str(0.314).split("0.")[-1].format('')
```

Comment: sorry, I think my question was a bit unclear. I made an edit to clarify.

Comment: I understood your question, try what I have mentioned above, you will achieve what you want, try it out `string  = "." + str(some_number).split("0.")[-1]`

Comment: your hack works, although I think `lstrip` is clearer in terms of code readability - but the question is: how to achieve it with `'{ }'.format()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `format()`, then try as below.

```py
print("Hello {0}, your balance is {1}.".format("Adam", "0.314".lstrip('0')))
```

Just use `lstrip()` within format function, you don't need to write additional line of code.

Comment: this is about how to use ONLY `'{}'.format()`, i.e. what you put in the curly braces. As I stated in the question, "find x" to get `'{x}'.format(0.314) == '.314'`. Furthermore, the input is of numeric type, not string.